# Obsolete "Use GetAddress(ScriptPubKeyType.Legacy) instead"

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, nbitcoin

```
using System;
using NBitcoin;

namespace RSA
{
    public class RSA
    {
        public static Wallet KeyGenerate()
        {
            Key  privateKey = new Key();

            var v = privateKey.GetBitcoinSecret(Network.Main).GetAddress();
            var address = BitcoinAddress.Create(v.ToString(), Network.Main);

            return new Wallet { PublicKey = v.ToString(), PrivateKey = privateKey.GetBitcoinSecret(Network.Main).ToString() };
        }
    }
}
```

I got this kind of warning, anyone please help how to fix it?

[image]

Comment: What is the problem? Simply use the code provided by the warning?

Comment: can you tell me what should I use from the warning code, thanks

Comment: `GetAddress(ScriptPublicKeyType.Legacy)`, it's standing in the warning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As `Progman` says,you can use `GetAddress(ScriptPublicKeyType.Legacy)` to instead `BitcoinSecret.getAddress()`.

Here is the usage of GetAddress(ScriptPublicKeyType.Legacy):

```
var v = privateKey.PubKey.GetAddress(ScriptPubKeyType.Legacy, Network.Main);
```

In addition,if you don't want to change the method.You can use `[Obsolete]`.

Here is a demo worked:
Program.cs：

```
[Obsolete]
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        KeyGenerate();
    }

    public static Wallet KeyGenerate()
    {
        Key privateKey = new Key();

        var v = privateKey.GetBitcoinSecret(Network.Main).GetAddress();
        Console.WriteLine(v);
        var v1 = privateKey.PubKey.GetAddress(ScriptPubKeyType.Legacy, Network.Main);
        Console.WriteLine(v1);
        var address = BitcoinAddress.Create(v.ToString(), Network.Main);

        return new Wallet { PublicKey = v.ToString(), PrivateKey = privateKey.GetBitcoinSecret(Network.Main).ToString() };
    }
}
```

Result:

[image]